# How to calculate (in R) how many customers are in the store currently

Tags: r, function

I have a dataset of about 10000 rows. The first column is the order of customers. The second column is his entering time. The third column is the time when he leaves the store. Therefore, the first row represents the first customer came in at 00:01 Jan 1 2016 and left at 13:28 Jan 01 2016. I want to create the fourth column which indicates how many customers are currently in the store. How am I supposed to do this?

```
     No.  entering_time         leaving_time          CustomerAtStore
 1   1    2016-01-01 00:01:00   2016-01-01 13:28:00   0
 2   2    2016-01-01 00:05:00   2016-01-01 13:32:00   1
 3   3    2016-01-01 00:08:00   2016-01-01 00:14:00   2
 4   4    2016-01-01 00:14:00   2016-01-01 02:43:00   2
 5   5    2016-01-01 00:17:00   2016-01-01 01:00:00   3
 6   6    2016-01-01 00:35:00   2016-01-01 04:09:00   4
 7   7    2016-01-01 00:37:00   2016-01-01 01:19:00   5
 8   8    2016-01-01 00:39:00   2016-01-01 20:26:00
 9   9    2016-01-01 00:52:00   2016-01-01 03:44:00
10  10    2016-01-01 00:54:00   2016-01-01 04:49:00
```

Here is my pseudocode, inspired by Python.
1. create an empty list.
2. use for loop to run the iteration.
3. append each row into the created list.
4. use if statement to compare the new customer's entering time and all the leaving time of those who already are in the list. Delete those who leave earlier than or equal to the new customer's entering time.
5. return the length of the list and assign this number to the correspondind field.

That is my idea. But I don't know how to make it happen in R.
Many thanks.

Comment: Does the colum 'customeratstore' refer to enterint time or leaving time?

Comment: Something like `library(dplyr) ; df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(in_store = sum(.$entering_time <= entering_time & .$leaving_time > entering_time))` or `df$in_store <- sapply(df$entering_time, function(enter){sum(df$entering_time <= enter & df$leaving_time > enter)})`

Comment: Hi Heroka, The value of the fourth column should indicate at exactly the entering time of that customer, how many customers are already in the store. For example, at 00:01 Jan 1 2016 when the first customer is about to come in, there is no customer in the store. Therefore, the value of this field is 0.   However, after 13 minutes, at 00:14 Jan 1 2016 when the fourth customer is about to come in, there are 2 customers (the first and the second) in the store. The third customer just left (00:14 Jan 1 2016). Thank you for giving me the chance to clarify it.

Comment: Hi Alistaire, thanks for the answer. I tried the second answer and it worked. However, I am not familiar with dplyr. But I will try to figure it out. Thanks for the direction.