# R Filtering data in loop using items in vector

Tags: r

I am attempting to speed some process up, so that I do not have to edit the year manually each time. I am certainly no expert in R, not sure if this is too easy to ask. It seems like it works for the first item in the vector, since the result is right.

I would like to print the amount of rows in a filtered dataset, for each year.
library(dplyr)

```
getData <- function(){
  data <- read.csv("data.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

data <- getData()
years <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016")
nbh <- "SomeVar"

for(year in years){
  data <- filter(data, grepl(year, Created.Date) & grepl(nbh, SomeColumn))
  print(nrow(data))
}
```

However, it just outputs this, where the first one is correct:

```
[1] 2
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
```

Is this because it filters the data the first time, it then has only two records, which causes for the next ones to be 0?

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer without knowing what your data looks like. Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @BLT I do not think this has to do with the data itself, but more about the loop and the filtering of data itself. This applies to any dataset used. Unfortunately I am not allowed to share any data

Comment: @dnsko, I'm not allowed to share any of my company's data, either. But you can create a fake dataset that has the same type of information as yours, but isn't proprietary. See what I did for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855554/count-people-present-within-specified-date-range

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but personally I prefer simulated data. With a reproducible example, this can be solved in seconds. Note also that you don't need to define functions to get things done. Just do `data <- read.csv(...)`. You can also probably use `group_by` to split the data according to year...

Comment: @dnsko you may be right that the data isn't what's wrong, but without some data to run your code on, it's very difficult to be sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your dataset in your for loop. Try

```
for(year in years){
  data_temp <- filter(data, grepl(year, Created.Date) & grepl(nbh, SomeColumn))
  print(nrow(data_temp))
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly .. Thought something had to be wrong there since the first one was good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can probably modify this to fit your bill.

```
library(dplyr)

xy <- data.frame(letters = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE),
                 years = sample(seq(from = 2010, to = 2015, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 values = rnorm(100))

xy %>%
  group_by(years) %>%
  filter(letters %in% c("a", "b", "c")) %>%
  count()

# A tibble: 6 × 2
  years     n
  <dbl> <int>
1  2010     5
2  2011     2
3  2012     3
4  2013     1
5  2014     1
6  2015     3
```